# Kotlin: Passing data/array from Recyclerview Activity to Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to pass an array from my Recyclerview Activity to its Adapter as such:

```
    //Setting NavBar Title
    val navBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra(FirstCustomViewHolder.LESSON_TITLE_KEY)
    supportActionBar?.title = navBarTitle

    var content : Array<String>
    if (navBarTitle == "Introduction"){
        content = arrayOf("Intro1", "Intro2")
    }
    else{
        content = arrayOf(":esson1-1", "Lesson 1-2")
    }
```

I am passing the array as such:

```
    recyclerView_main.adapter = SecondAdapter(content)
```

And I am getting an angry red underline as shown below. 
[image: @the var content]

On mouse-over the pop-up error reads:
`Too many arguments for public constructor......`
Is there a proper way to pass an array or variable to my adapter? I am fairly new to Kotlin and appreciate and pointers.

Thank you.

Edit:
As requested, this is my adapter class:

```
class SecondAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondCustomViewGolder>(){


    //Variable below to be replaced by array from Activity
    var lessons = arrayOf("Satu", "Dua", "Tiga", "Empat", "Lima", "Enam", "Tujuh",
        "Lapan", "Sembilan")

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lessons.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SecondCustomViewGolder {
        var layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_row, parent, false)
        return SecondCustomViewGolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SecondCustomViewGolder, position: Int) {

    }
}
class SecondCustomViewGolder(var viewTwo : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewTwo){

}
```

Comment: can you please show your adapter class?

Comment: Your SecondAdapter class doesn't have any parameters in its constructor. You should write something like `class SecondAdapter(private val lessons: List<something>): RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondCustomViewGolder>()`. You can read more about Kotlin constructors here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your SecondAdapter class constructor accept an Array as an argument? If not, you must add it there. The error is because you're trying to pass an argument to a constructor that accepts no arguments.

**EDIT**

Do it like so:

```
class SecondAdapter(val lessonArray: Array<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondCustomViewGolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lessons.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SecondCustomViewGolder {
        var layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_row, parent, false)
        return SecondCustomViewGolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SecondCustomViewGolder, position: Int) {

    }
}
class SecondCustomViewGolder(var viewTwo : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewTwo){

}
```

I made it a `val` since it's my preference. If you intend to modify the variable, than you just declare it as a `var` in the constructor. There's no need to assign it inside the class. Just declaring it in the constructor makes it accessible throughout the class.

Comment: Can u show me an example of doing so? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter)
and use [submitList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#submitList(kotlin.collections.MutableList))